# Por que não pode chamar classes "coladas" CSS

Tags: css

Por que não posso chamar classes "coladas", assim:

```
.div1.div2.div3 {
   blablabla;
}
```

Somente posso faze assim:

```
.div1 .div2 .div3{
   blablabla
}
```

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do primeiro modo:

```
.div1.div2.div3 {
   blablabla;
}
```

Você está selecionando um elemento que possua as três classes, tal qual:

```
<div class="div1 div2 div3"></div>
```

No segundo caso você está trabalhando com a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ou seja div1 > div2 > div3, em relação a herança. Selecionando assim o elemento `.div3` *filho* do elemento `.div2` *filho* do elemento `.div1`.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Quando der tempo eu marco como certo!